# Change font color of UIAlertView

Tags: fonts, ios7, uialertview

I really don't like that `UIAlertView` has blue font color. Is there a way to change it? It doesn't even correspond to the system settings as the system font are black..

Now I know about the rule not to subclass UIAlertView, to use it as-is etc etc....but I remember Apple introducing maybe on WWDC that the apps will have a general "style" that will influence all the system parts perhaps...?

Comment: have a look into this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43651395/3024579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot customize the appearance of `UIAlertView`. Here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView

Comment: There isn't. I tried this before. As you indicated earlier, you cannot subclass UIAlertView. This question would be good for a bounty since many other threads exist on the same subject.