# UIAlertController custom font, size, color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I am using new UIAlertController for showing alerts. I have this code:

```
// nil titles break alert interface on iOS 8.0, so we'll be using empty strings
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: title == nil ? @"": title message: message preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: cancelButtonTitle style: UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler: nil];

[alert addAction: defaultAction];

UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
[rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now I want to change title and message font, color, size and so. What's best way to do this?

**Edit:**
I should insert whole code. I created category for UIView that I could show right alert for iOS version.

```
@implementation UIView (AlertCompatibility)

+( void )showSimpleAlertWithTitle:( NSString * )title
                          message:( NSString * )message
                cancelButtonTitle:( NSString * )cancelButtonTitle
{
    float iOSVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
    if (iOSVersion < 8.0f)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: title
                                                        message: message
                                                       delegate: nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle: cancelButtonTitle
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        // nil titles break alert interface on iOS 8.0, so we'll be using empty strings
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: title == nil ? @"": title
                                                                       message: message
                                                                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


        UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: cancelButtonTitle
                                                                style: UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                              handler: nil];

        [alert addAction: defaultAction];

        UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
        [rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: `DISCLAIMER:` To anyone who's reading the below answers. Apple will reject your app(s). If you tend use any private Api(s). And in the below answers THAT'S WHAT'S HAPPENING..

Answer (score 101):

Not sure if this is against private APIs/properties but using KVC works for me on ios8

```
UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Dont care what goes here, since we're about to change below" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
NSMutableAttributedString *hogan = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Presenting the great... Hulk Hogan!"];
[hogan addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50.0]
              range:NSMakeRange(24, 11)];
[alertVC setValue:hogan forKey:@"attributedTitle"];



UIAlertAction *button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Label text" 
                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                                    //add code to make something happen once tapped
}];
UIImage *accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"];
[button setValue:accessoryImage forKey:@"image"];
```

For the record, it is possible to change alert action's font as well, using those private APIs. Again, it may get you app rejected, I have not yet tried to submit such code.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Some title", style: .Default, handler: nil)
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some title")

let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 1.5, range: range)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 20.0)!, range: range)

alert.addAction(action)

presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

// this has to be set after presenting the alert, otherwise the internal property __representer is nil
guard let label = action.valueForKey("__representer")?.valueForKey("label") as? UILabel else { return }
label.attributedText = attributedText
```

For Swift 4.2 in XCode 10 and up the last 2 lines are now:

```
guard let label = (action!.value(forKey: "__representer")as? NSObject)?.value(forKey: "label") as? UILabel else { return }
        label.attributedText = attributedText
```

Comment: It's working. `attributedTitle` for title and `attributedMessage` for message. Not sure if it's best solution but for now it's good enough for me.

Comment: what all customization we can add on UIAlertController buttons??

Comment: How did you find the key `attributeTitle`? Understandably, `attributeMessage` is also a key but how did you find these? Is there a way I can look these up in some header files.

Comment: Thanks! I have a small question — one could use custom fonts and colors with the attribute tile and message in `UIAlertController`. How can one do the same with `UIAlertAction`?

Comment: @p0lAris i don't think you can (nor have i needed to or tried to)....looking at https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/e6eb5f69b3a744b151e8e4a2f27cb1ce129b7812/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertAction.h maybe you can try messing with the image key and use a pre-rendered image, instead of text? total shot in the dark....

Comment: I have a font scheme throughout the app, so changing the font for those labels seems quite necessary. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @p0lAris - Did you ever find a solution for customizing the font for `UIAlertAction`?

Comment: Nope. But I haven't seen the updates in iOS 9. Maybe it's there. :X

Comment: @p0lAris - I haven't found anything so far. We are still stuck dealing with strings for the `UIAlertAction` title, which I don't think you can customize the font for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532941/is-it-possible-to-set-custom-font-size-for-nsstring

Comment: As far as changing font on the`UIAlertAction` it is possible but defiantly not recommended. In order to change the font/BGColor you have to subclass and Apple clearly states in the docs that you aren't supposed to do this and could result in your app being rejected from the app store

Comment: can't emphasize the importance of attributedMessage as mentioned by @LiborZapletal

Comment: I hope none of you are planning on releasing this to the app store as it uses private APIs. Seriously, I have no idea why these answers are ever accepted on Stackoverflow when they're not really 'answers'. These are hacks that you may or may not get away with publishing in the application store.

Comment: For case of releasing app on app store, some of the private api uses are allowed by Apple, but it should not use the apis which may harm or affects the system/privacy of user. So, Probably this answer may be accepted by many people due to this only. And probably it might not be affecting on app store. Can someone who have used this, can they confirm that their app is not rejected?

Answer (score 69):

You can change the button color by applying a tint color to an UIAlertController.

On iOS 9, if the window tint color was set to a custom color, you have to apply the tint color right after presenting the alert. Otherwise the tint color will be reset to your custom window tint color.

```
// In your AppDelegate for example:
window?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

// Elsewhere in the App:
let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))

// Works on iOS 8, but not on iOS 9
// On iOS 9 the button color will be red
alertVC.view.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

// Necessary to apply tint on iOS 9
alertVC.view.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Comment: To clarify, setting the tintColor after presenting the controller works on both iOS 8 and 9, so it is not necessary to set it twice.

Comment: Thanks for adding a Swift answer and a workaround for this issue in iOS 9.

Comment: When i tap and drag my finger down, it will again goes to default colour. Any idea?

Comment: This is really the only decent answer here.

Answer (score 53):

You can change color of button text using this code:

```
alertC.view.tintColor = your color;
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: @esilver did you manage to find a solution that works with iOS9?

Comment: I did not. I created a bug report with Apple, #22391695.

Comment: More informations about this. It seems that when you scroll in a long list items, the one you touch to scroll becomes blue...

Comment: None of this work on UIAlertController in iOS9 and 9.1.. Dont know what Apple guys are upto... Need to manually change the window tint every time an alert controller is called and change it back in the handler.

Comment: It works with iOS 9.3, unless you touch up outiside: comes back to system blue

Answer (score 39):

> **In Xcode 8 Swift 3.0**

```
@IBAction func touchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //to change font of title and message.
    let titleFont = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Bold", size: 18.0)!]
    let messageFont = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Roman", size: 12.0)!]

    let titleAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Title Here", attributes: titleFont)
    let messageAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Message Here", attributes: messageFont)

    alertController.setValue(titleAttrString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
    alertController.setValue(messageAttrString, forKey: "attributedMessage")

    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 1", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("\(action.title)")
    }

    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 2", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("\(action.title)")
    }

    let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 3", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("\(action.title)")
    }

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("\(action.title)")
    }

    alertController.addAction(action1)
    alertController.addAction(action2)
    alertController.addAction(action3)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    alertController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    alertController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 40

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

***Output***

[image: UIAlertController custom font, size and color]

Comment: Sorry bro, this is start up. If required in feature i will inform to you...

Answer (score 25):

A Swift translation of the @dupuis2387 answer. Worked out the syntax to set the `UIAlertController` title's color and font via KVC using the `attributedTitle` key.

```
let message = "Some message goes here."
let alertController = UIAlertController(
    title: "", // This gets overridden below.
    message: message,
    preferredStyle: .Alert
)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { _ -> Void in
}
alertController.addAction(okAction)

let fontAwesomeHeart = "\u{f004}"
let fontAwesomeFont = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: 17)!
let customTitle:NSString = "I \(fontAwesomeHeart) Swift" // Use NSString, which lets you call rangeOfString()
let systemBoldAttributes:[String : AnyObject] = [ 
    // setting the attributed title wipes out the default bold font,
    // so we need to reconstruct it.
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
]
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: customTitle as String, attributes:systemBoldAttributes)
let fontAwesomeAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: fontAwesomeFont,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()
]
let matchRange = customTitle.rangeOfString(fontAwesomeHeart)
attributedString.addAttributes(fontAwesomeAttributes, range: matchRange)
alertController.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: What about "OK" button? Can we customize it?

Comment: @HassanTaleb I haven't found a great way to customize the button. You can set the `tintColor` on the `view` or via `appearanceWhenContainedIn`, but the tint goes away as soon as you touch it. Still searching for answers though.

Comment: @AbdulMomenعبدالمؤمن What error message are you seeing? The code snippet assumes FontAwesome is already set up.

Comment: @RobertChen didn't recognize ```attributedTitle``` in  ```alertController.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")```

Comment: @RobertChen to solve the issue just put the tint after : `self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)` , can we change the font of the button "OK"?

Comment: Isn't this considered a private api?

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 5 and 5.1**. Create a separate file and put UIAlertController Customization code there

```
import Foundation
import  UIKit

extension UIAlertController {

  //Set background color of UIAlertController
  func setBackgroudColor(color: UIColor) {
    if let bgView = self.view.subviews.first,
      let groupView = bgView.subviews.first,
      let contentView = groupView.subviews.first {
      contentView.backgroundColor = color
    }
  }

  //Set title font and title color
  func setTitle(font: UIFont?, color: UIColor?) {
    guard let title = self.title else { return }
    let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title)//1
    if let titleFont = font {
      attributeString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : titleFont],//2
        range: NSMakeRange(0, title.utf8.count))
    }
    if let titleColor = color {
      attributeString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : titleColor],//3
        range: NSMakeRange(0, title.utf8.count))
    }
    self.setValue(attributeString, forKey: "attributedTitle")//4
  }

  //Set message font and message color
  func setMessage(font: UIFont?, color: UIColor?) {
    guard let title = self.message else {
      return
    }
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title)
    if let titleFont = font {
      attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : titleFont], range: NSMakeRange(0, title.utf8.count))
    }
    if let titleColor = color {
      attributedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : titleColor], range: NSMakeRange(0, title.utf8.count))
    }
    self.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage")//4
  }

  //Set tint color of UIAlertController
  func setTint(color: UIColor) {
    self.view.tintColor = color
  }
}
```

Now On any action Show Alert

```
  func tapShowAlert(sender: UIButton) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!!", message: "This is custom alert message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    // Change font and color of title
    alertController.setTitle(font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26), color: UIColor.yellow)
    // Change font and color of message
    alertController.setMessage(font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-HeavyItalic", size: 18), color: UIColor.red)
    // Change background color of UIAlertController
    alertController.setBackgroudColor(color: UIColor.black)
    let actnOk = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    let actnCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(actnOk)
    alertController.addAction(actnCancel)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

Result

[image]

Comment: are we accessing any private Api's over here .? have you released any app with these many custom alert properties?

Comment: @YashBedi it's using private APIs and Apple might reject your app for "non-public API" usage. No, I haven't released any app.

Comment: This is mentioned on Apple developer site ->

Important
**The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.**

Comment: @Darkglow Please mention the error. I am able to build successfully the same code with swift 5.1

Answer (score 14):

Use `UIAppearance` protocol. Example for setting a font - create a category to extend  `UILabel`:

```
@interface UILabel (FontAppearance)
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIFont * appearanceFont UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@end


@implementation UILabel (FontAppearance)

-(void)setAppearanceFont:(UIFont *)font {
    if (font)
        [self setFont:font];
}

-(UIFont *)appearanceFont {
    return self.font;
}

@end
```

And its usage:

```
UILabel * appearanceLabel = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:UIAlertController.class, nil];
[appearanceLabel setAppearanceFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10]]; //for example
```

Tested and working with style `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`, but I guess it will work with `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` too.

P.S. Better check for class availability instead of iOS version:

```
if ([UIAlertController class]) {
    // UIAlertController code (iOS 8)
} else {
    // UIAlertView code (pre iOS 8)
}
```

Comment: It's working but this way I can't have different size for message and for title.

Comment: This works but when an action is clicked, the font reverts back to the original size? Does this happen for you?

Comment: I have the same problem @Larry and I haven't found a way to deal with it.. have you?

Answer (score 12):

Use `UIAppearance` protocol. Do more hacks with `appearanceFont` to change font for `UIAlertAction`.

Create a category for `UILabel`

UILabel+FontAppearance.h

```
@interface UILabel (FontAppearance)

@property (nonatomic, copy) UIFont * appearanceFont UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

@end
```

UILabel+FontAppearance.m

```
@implementation UILabel (FontAppearance)

- (void)setAppearanceFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    if (self.tag == 1001) {
        return;
    }

    BOOL isBold = (self.font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits & UIFontDescriptorTraitBold);
    const CGFloat* colors = CGColorGetComponents(self.textColor.CGColor);

    if (self.font.pointSize == 14) {
        // set font for UIAlertController title
        self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
    } else if (self.font.pointSize == 13) {
        // set font for UIAlertController message
        self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
    } else if (isBold) {
        // set font for UIAlertAction with UIAlertActionStyleCancel
        self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    } else if ((*colors) == 1) {
        // set font for UIAlertAction with UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
        self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    } else {
        // set font for UIAlertAction with UIAlertActionStyleDefault
        self.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    }
    self.tag = 1001;
}

- (UIFont *)appearanceFont
{
    return self.font;
}

@end
```

Usage:

add

`[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:UIAlertController.class, nil] setAppearanceFont:nil];`

in `AppDelegate.m` to make it work for all `UIAlertController`.

Comment: The title in iOS 8.3 is 13pt and bold so I changed the condition to
`if (self.font.pointSize == 13 && isBold) {`

Comment: You mentioned changing the font for `UIAlertAction`. But as far as I can tell, `UIAlertAction` does not use a `UILabel`. It uses an `NSString`. https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/3dde29deb7000cfac59d3e5473a71557123f29ea/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertAction.h I don't know how you could customize the font for an `NSString`.

Comment: UIAlertAction is not a view class at all. It is an abstract class describing the action. The view itself is then generated inside UIAlertController. You therefore set the appearance contained in UIAlertController.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using it.

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Add one line (AppDelegate) and works for all UIAlertController.

Comment: As this is now deprecated, use [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIAlertController class]]] setTintColor:newColor]; instead

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

Example of custom font on the title.
Same things for other components such as message or actions.

```
    let titleAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: Constant.Strings.cancelAbsence, 
            attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name:"FONT_NAME",size: FONT_SIZE)]
    )

    let alertController = UIAlertController(
        title: "",
        message: "",
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.YOUR_STYLE
    )

    alertController.setValue(titleAttributed, forKey : "attributedTitle")
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use an external library like [PMAlertController](https://github.com/Codeido/PMAlertController) without using workaround, where you can substitute Apple's uncustomizable UIAlertController with a super customizable alert.

**Compatible with Xcode 8, Swift 3 and Objective-C**

[image: PMAlertController example]

### Features:

- [x] Header View
- [x] Header Image (Optional)
- [x] Title
- [x] Description message
- [x] Customizations: fonts, colors, dimensions & more
- [x] 1, 2 buttons (horizontally) or 3+ buttons (vertically)
- [x] Closure when a button is pressed
- [x] Text Fields support
- [x] Similar implementation to UIAlertController
- [x] Cocoapods
- [x] Carthage
- [x] Animation with UIKit Dynamics
- [x] Objective-C compatibility
- [x] Swift 2.3 & Swift 3 support

Comment: Does PMAlertController allow for word wrap when the text is long in the action buttons?

Comment: @zeeple consider that the action button is a subclass of UIButton.
Something like that 
`actionButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` works well.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 4.1 and Xcode 10

```
//Displaying alert with multiple actions and custom font ans size
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

let titFont = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Bold", size: 15.0)!]
let msgFont = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Roman", size: 13.0)!]

let titAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Title Here", attributes: titFont)
let msgAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Message Here", attributes: msgFont)

alert.setValue(titAttrString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
alert.setValue(msgAttrString, forKey: "attributedMessage")

let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 1", style: .default) { (action) in
    print("\(String(describing: action.title))")
}

let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 2", style: .default) { (action) in
    print("\(String(describing: action.title))")
}

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action) in
    print("\(String(describing: action.title))")
}
alert.addAction(action1)
alert.addAction(action2)
alert.addAction(okAction)

alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blue
alert.view.layer.cornerRadius = 40
// //If required background colour 
// alert.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
})
```

Comment: your answer needs a update , `self.present(alertController, animated: true)` or `self.present(alert, animated: true)`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an extension for Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1:

```
extension UIAlertController{

func addColorInTitleAndMessage(color:UIColor,titleFontSize:CGFloat = 18, messageFontSize:CGFloat = 13){

    let attributesTitle = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: titleFontSize)]
    let attributesMessage = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: messageFontSize)]
    let attributedTitleText = NSAttributedString(string: self.title ?? "", attributes: attributesTitle)
    let attributedMessageText = NSAttributedString(string: self.message ?? "", attributes: attributesMessage)

    self.setValue(attributedTitleText, forKey: "attributedTitle")
    self.setValue(attributedMessageText, forKey: "attributedMessage")

}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I just completed a replacement for `UIAlertController`. [This](https://github.com/drosenstark/SimpleAlert) is the only sensible way to go, I think:

---

### Old

Here's my method in Swift which mashes up a lot of information from answers here

```
func changeAlert(alert: UIAlertController, backgroundColor: UIColor, textColor: UIColor, buttonColor: UIColor?) {
    let view = alert.view.firstSubview().firstSubview()
    view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

    // set color to UILabel font
    setSubviewLabelsToTextColor(textColor, view: view)

    // set font to alert via KVC, otherwise it'll get overwritten
    let titleAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: alert.title!,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)])
    alert.setValue(titleAttributed, forKey: "attributedTitle")


    let messageAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: alert.message!,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)])
    alert.setValue(messageAttributed, forKey: "attributedMessage")


    // set the buttons to non-blue, if we have buttons
    if let buttonColor = buttonColor {
        alert.view.tintColor = buttonColor
    }
}

func setSubviewLabelsToTextColor(textColor: UIColor, view:UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
            label.textColor = textColor
        } else {
            setSubviewLabelsToTextColor(textColor, view: subview)
        }
    }
}
```

This works in some situations perfectly, and in others it's a total fail (the tint colors do not show as expected).

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with setting the tint color on the view after presenting; even if you do it in the completion block of presentViewController:animated:completion:, it causes a flicker effect on the color of the button titles.  This is sloppy, unprofessional and completely unacceptable.

Other solutions presented depend on the view hierarchy remaining static, something that Apple is loathe to do.  Expect those solutions to fail in future releases of iOS.

The one sure-fire way to solve this problem and to do it everywhere, is via adding a category to UIAlertController and swizzling the viewWillAppear.

The header:

```
//
//  UIAlertController+iOS9TintFix.h
//
//  Created by Flor, Daniel J on 11/2/15.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIAlertController (iOS9TintFix)

+ (void)tintFix;

- (void)swizzledViewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

The implementation:

```
//
//  UIAlertController+iOS9TintFix.m
//
//  Created by Flor, Daniel J on 11/2/15.
//

#import "UIAlertController+iOS9TintFix.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIAlertController (iOS9TintFix)

+ (void)tintFix {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Method method  = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(viewWillAppear:));
        Method swizzle = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzledViewWillAppear:));
        method_exchangeImplementations(method, swizzle);});
}

- (void)swizzledViewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self swizzledViewWillAppear:animated];
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        if (view.tintColor == self.view.tintColor) {
            //only do those that match the main view, so we don't strip the red-tint from destructive buttons.
            self.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
            [view setNeedsDisplay];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Add a .pch (precompiled header) to your project and include the category:

```
#import "UIAlertController+iOS9TintFix.h"
```

Make sure you register your pch in the project properly, and it will include the category methods in every class that uses the UIAlertController.

Then, in your app delegates didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, import your category and call

```
[UIAlertController tintFix];
```

and it will automatically propagate to every single instance of UIAlertController within your app, whether launched by your code or anyone else's.

This solution works for both iOS 8.X and iOS 9.X and lacks the flicker of the tint change post-presentation approach.  It is also completely agnostic with respect to the view hierarchy of the sub-views of the UIAlertController.

Happy hacking!

Comment: This solution works, mostly. On device rotate, however, the tints go back to the way they were, before the swizzling.

Comment: Dhiraj, I just tested this again in a project setup explicitly to explore your findings, and I do not concur.  The tint does not go back to the way it was on rotate.

Comment: Verified functional on xcode 6.4, and xcode 7.0.  Running simulators of all variations of 8.X and 9.0.  If requested, I will put the project up on github.

Comment: Well you could go ahead and put up a project, but this is what I was seeing happening to me. It was also not working on iPad. Based on your method swizzling idea, however, I *was* able to make it work by swizzling viewDidLayoutSubviews, though.

Comment: If you put up a project, then I could submit a pull request with the viewDidLayoutSubviews swizzle, which is what I've just used and submitted in the latest build of my app to the App Store and you can have a look, maybe?

Comment: Sure, sorry I've been offline for a spell, but let me get one pushed up there for you.

Comment: This is the test project I wrote to isolate the swizzle from all other aspects of the codebase:

https://github.com/DJFlor/UIAlertControllerTest

Comment: Works great, even on rotation, when swizzling `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 3):

Please find [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/em91fh00fv3ut4h/Archive.zip?dl=0) category. I am able to change FONT and Color of UIAlertAction and UIAlertController.

Use:

```
UILabel * appearanceLabel = [UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:UIAlertController.class, nil];
[appearanceLabel setAppearanceFont:yourDesireFont]];
```

Comment: Please, paste the code here or use a service that does not require people to log in.

Answer (score 2):

Solution/Hack for iOS9

```
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Test Error" message:@"This is a test" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSLog(@"Alert View Displayed");
 [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"View Controller Displayed");
    }];
```

Comment: I tried this. Note that you're reverting the window tint setting once the alert controller is presented. I see the color switching back right on the alert controller. I believe the revertion must be done once any action is tapped.

Comment: Thanks @Germán for pointing that out.. Made the changes to the code. I am handling the revert in the AlertAction as of now.. But yes I agree that can be handled in the dimiss handler too

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 9.0 and above use this code in app delegate

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIAlertController class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

> Swift 5.0

```
let titleAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is a title", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "CustomFontName", size: 17) as Any])
let messageAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is a message", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "CustomFontName", size: 13) as Any])

alertController.setValue(titleAttrString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
alertController.setValue(messageAttrString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

Answer (score 1):

I work for Urban Outfitters. We have an open source pod, `URBNAlert`, that we used in all of our apps. It's based off of `UIAlertController`, but is highly customizable.

Source is here: https://github.com/urbn/URBNAlert

Or simply install by the pod by placing `URBNAlert` in your Podfile

Heres some sample code:

```
URBNAlertViewController *uac = [[URBNAlertViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Title of my message can be up to 2 lines long. It wraps and centers." message:@"And the message that is a bunch of text. And the message that is a bunch of text. And the message that is a bunch of text."];

// You can customize style elements per alert as well. These will override the global style just for this alert.
uac.alertStyler.blurTintColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
uac.alertStyler.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
uac.alertStyler.textFieldEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 15.0);
uac.alertStyler.titleColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
uac.alertStyler.titleFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:30];
uac.alertStyler.messageColor = [UIColor blackColor];
uac.alertStyler.alertMinWidth = @150;
uac.alertStyler.alertMaxWidth = @200;
// many more styling options available 

[uac addAction:[URBNAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" actionType:URBNAlertActionTypeNormal actionCompleted:^(URBNAlertAction *action) {
      // Do something
}]];

[uac addAction:[URBNAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" actionType:URBNAlertActionTypeCancel actionCompleted:^(URBNAlertAction *action) {
      // Do something
}]];

[uac show];
```

Comment: Does this support the ActionSheet style?

Comment: @Danpe it does not, it is is purely just for Alerts.. That being said.. if its something you desire create an issue on the repo. That is something we have discussed adding support for before

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of one button like CANCEL to the red color you can use this style property called UIAlertActionStyle.destructive :

```
let prompt = UIAlertController.init(title: "Reset Password", message: "Enter Your E-mail :", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Submit", style: .default) { (action) in
              //your code
}

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive) { (action) in
                //your code
        }
        prompt.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
        prompt.addAction(okAction)
        prompt.addAction(cancelAction)
        present(prompt, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit clunky, but this works for me right now to set background and text colors. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863460/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-the-uialertcontroller).

```
UIView * firstView = alertController.view.subviews.firstObject;
    UIView * nextView = firstView.subviews.firstObject;
    nextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: It does work for the background color but it never changes the tint color this is what I am a bit confused about

Answer (score 0):

I have created one method objective-C

```
-(void)customAlertTitle:(NSString*)title message:(NSString*)message{
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 80)];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, 50)];
titleLabel.text = title;
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[subView addSubview:titleLabel];

UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 270, 50)];
messageLabel.text = message;
messageLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[subView addSubview:messageLabel];

[alertView setValue:subView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alertView show];
}
```

Code wokring perfectly on Xcode 8.3.1. You can customise according to requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I just use this kind of demand, seemingly and system, details are slightly different, so we are ... OC realized Alert and Sheet popup window encapsulation.

Often encountered in daily development need to add a figure to Alert or change a button color, such as "simple" demand, today brings a and system components of highly similar and can fully meet the demand of customized packaging components.

Github:https://github.com/ReverseScale/RSCustomAlertView