# Change title and message font of alert using UIAlertController in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uialertcontroller

I am trying to change the title and message font for an alert shown using UIAlertController
I am trying to do using an NSAttributedStirng, but it gives compiler error that a NSAttributed string cannot be taken instead of Stirng
I tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530577/840520)

```
var title_attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : CustomFonts.HELVETICA_NEUE_MEDIUM_16]
var msg_attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : CustomFonts.HELVETICA_NEUE_REGULAR_14]
var title = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Done", attributes:title_attrs)

var msg = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"The job is done ", attributes:msg_attrs)
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: title , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
```

Can someone guide me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Apple removed the attributedTitle and -message from the API. It was never part of the public [API](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIAlertControllerStyle) so it might be that Apple will not allow your app in the app store if you used it.

You should use the UIAlertController as is. If you want to customise it a bit see this [NSHipster post](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/). If you want more control, create a custom View to display.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3** Version:

```
extension UIAlertController {
    func changeFont(view: UIView, font:UIFont) {
        for item in view.subviews {
            if item.isKind(of: UICollectionView.self) {
                let col = item as! UICollectionView
                for  row in col.subviews{
                    changeFont(view: row, font: font)
                }
            }
            if item.isKind(of: UILabel.self) {
                let label = item as! UILabel
                label.font = font
            }else {
                changeFont(view: item, font: font)
            }

        }
    }

    open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let font = YOUR_FONT
        changeFont(view: self.view, font: font! )
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my life!

Comment: Code is woking as I excepted but small issue is, When i tap and drag my finger down, it will again goes to default font size. Any idea?

Comment: The problem of This approach is there is no difference between title and message label text sizes.

Comment: You can check label's font point size, and change the font accordingly.

Comment: I tried this solution to increase font size on iPad. It's work fine, but alert showing with  very small width. How to increase alert width?

Comment: @tdtkien if you mean the width of presented alert view, i'm afraid you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

```
    let myString  = "Alert Title"
    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])
    myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:myString.characters.count))
    alertController.setValue(myMutableString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
    alertController.setValue(myMutableString, forKey: "attributedMessage")
```

Comment: It leads to crash for me on Swift 5

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UIAlertController {
    func changeFont(view:UIView,font:UIFont) {
        for item in view.subviews {
            if item.isKindOfClass(UICollectionView) {
                let col = item as! UICollectionView
                for  row in col.subviews{
                    changeFont(row, font: font)
                }
            }
            if item.isKindOfClass(UILabel) {
                let label = item as! UILabel
                label.font = font
            }else {
                changeFont(item, font: font)
            }

        }
    }
    public override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        let font = UIFont(name: YourFontName, size: YourFontSize)
        changeFont(self.view, font: font! )
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicated answer.