# Change Alertview UIAlertController Buttons and Title color in iOS

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, tintcolor

I wanted to change my alert view title and button color as per my App theme and for this, i have found the many solutions as below:

```
alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

But above code is changing only button title color not the Alert title.

Testing on iOS 11 using Xcode 9.1

Comment: tintColor only works for button title , Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662591/swift-how-to-change-uialertcontrollers-title-color

Comment: @RajeevUdayan do you have any idea to change text color without using attribute string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to change Alert title:

```
 alertController.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: "test", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15),NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]), forKey: "attributedTitle")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have changed few syntaxes and updated and accepted your answer.

Comment: If you have any idea to subclassing of Alertviewcontroller and then change text color without attribute string then please let me know.

Comment: @Alok as per apple doc `UIAlertController` is not supporting subclassing. But if you want to use 'UIAlertController' with text color you can create common method in one class and use that method to present `UIAlertController`.