# Change tint color for call alert confirmation

Tags: ios, swift

So I want the users to be able to start a call from the app, fo this I'm using:

```
func prepareCall(to phoneNumber:String) {
    let callURL = URL(string:"telprompt://\(phoneNumber)")!
    UIApplication.shared.open(callURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
  }
```

Everything works fine, is just a theme issue what I've got here.
I've also set global tint like so:

```
    self.window?.tintColor = //my main theme color
```

So my whole app has a base tint color applied to all alerts, buttons, etc. But when the user is prompted with the alert confirmation button it has that blue default tint.

[image: alert]

Is there any why to change this alert tint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift How to change UIAlertController's Title Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662591/swift-how-to-change-uialertcontrollers-title-color)

Comment: that's a completely different question @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: This is a default behavior and provided by the system. It’s also localizable by default. I think it’s not changeable. Also you can simply use `tel://`

Comment: @SebitasSg Exactly! You’re right!

Comment: That's what I thought @Mannopson, just wasn't sure, thanks, FYI I'm using telprompt: for the user to be able to comeback to the app after the call.

Comment: @SebitasSg Also make it as an optional feature ( Phone call ). Because the iPad or the iPod touch can’t open this `url` `( tel: )`. Therefore use the `canOpenURL` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible , at least in iOS 11.4.1.

Example view:

[image: 00]

the corresponding  view hierarchy ,

[image: 111]

the blue alert is not there.

the noisy blue alert is not within your app. It is of the system.

More evidence:

Xcode stop running, the blue alert is still there. The app project is terminated.

[image: 333]