# How to change the color of UIAlertAction Title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to change the color of title of UIAlertActionSheet.

"alert.view.tintColor" changes the color of all the action buttons but not title.

Comment: There is no such thing as a UIAlertActionSheet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662591/swift-how-to-change-uialertcontrollers-title-color/31688708

Comment: By UIAlertActionSheet, I mean when the preferred style of UIAlertController is actionSheet

Comment: I wouldn't as it's using private properties that might change on next release and might make your app crash. I would use a custom alert that looks like a `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this an it may work with you

```
let myCancelAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
            myCancelAlert.setValue(UIColor.black, forKey: "titleTextColor")
            alert.addAction(cancelAlert)
```

Comment: I am able to change color of "UIAlertAction" title but I want to change color of "UIAlertActionSheet" title