# Change background color of title (only) in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I found the following code in [How to change the background color of the UIAlertController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863460) to change the background color of a `UIAlertView`:

```
let subview = dialog.view.subviews.first! as UIView
let alertContentView = subview.subviews.first! as UIView
subview.subviews.top!
alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

However, it changes the background color of the entire view. How can I change only the background color of the title?

Comment: have you had a chance to look at the answers?

Comment: @RMenke I have check abhinav solution but it is not the answer I am looking for. It changes the foreground title, not the background

Comment: Updated answer without subclassing.

Comment: @RMenke it helps, thanks man :'D

Comment: you're welcome, was a nice tricky problem to work on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sample project](https://github.com/romainmenke/AlertControllerFun) -> Contains latest code

**Step one:**

Find a subview that has the right frame!

This little function will return the frame and address of all nested subviews.

We are looking for a subview that has a height that is smaller than that of the `UIAlertController` and has an `Origin` of `0,0`.
Height of my alertController was `128`

```
func subViewStack(view:UIView, levels: [Int]) {

    var currentLevels = levels
    currentLevels.append(0)

    for i in 0..<view.subviews.count {

        currentLevels[currentLevels.count - 1] = i

        let subView = view.subviews[i]
        print(subView.frame, "depth:", currentLevels)
        subViewStack(subView, levels: currentLevels)

    }

}
```

This prints stuff like this:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 270.0, 128.0) depth: [0, 0]

//frame - firstsubview - firstsubview
```

This might be a good candidate:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 270.0, 84.0) depth: [0, 1, 0, 0]
//frame - firstsubview - secondsubiew - firstsubview - firstsubview
```

This translates to this:

```
print(alertController.view.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[0].subviews[0].frame)
// prints (0.0, 0.0, 270.0, 84.0) -> Bingo!
```

---

**Step two:**

Color that subview!

```
alertController.view.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

If you set the colour before presenting the alertController it will crash.
Setting it in the completionHandler works.

```
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) { () -> Void in

    self.subViewStack(alertController.view, levels: [])
    print(alertController.view.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[0].subviews[0].frame)
    alertController.view.subviews[0].subviews[1].subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

}
```

---

**Step three**:

Make it safe!
If they ever change anything to the stack this will prevent your app from crashing. Your view might not be coloured but a crash is worse.

Extend UIView to be able to fetch subviews with one of the addresses we printed earlier. Use `guard`or `if let` to prevent accessing non-existent subviews.

```
extension UIView {

    // use the printed addresses to access the views. This is safe even if the UIView changes in an update.
    func getSubView(withAddress address:[Int]) -> UIView? {

        var currentView : UIView = self

        for index in address {

            guard currentView.subviews.count > index else {
                return nil
            }
            currentView = currentView.subviews[index]

        }
        return currentView
    }
}
```

---

**Step four:**

Since it is not allowed to subclass `UIAlertController` we might try to extend it. This won't give you access to `viewDidAppear` so you can't display the `UIAlertController` animated.

```
protocol CustomAlert {

    var view : UIView! { get }

}

extension CustomAlert {

    func titleBackgroundColor(color:UIColor) {

        if view == nil {
            return
        }

        if let titleBackground = view.getSubView(withAddress: [0, 1, 0, 0]) {
            titleBackground.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
}

extension UIAlertController : CustomAlert {

}
```

---

This gives you both the method to find any subviews you might want to alter and a way to add a custom function for it to that class. Without subclassing.

Call `titleBackgroundColor` in the completionHandler of `presentViewController` to set the color.

Comment: Is it okay to extend the UIAlertController? As in apple class reference states that you should not extend this class, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

Comment: @Christoper No it isn't ok. But it is possible. I don't know how this goes trough app review. If you don't present the alertcontroller animated you can just colour the background in the completion handler and then you don't need to sub class it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "myMessage", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "myTitle", attributes: [
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()
    ])

alertController.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
```

Comment: That changes the foreground color, not the background color.

Answer (score 1):

try with following its works for me.

```
 let confirmAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Application Name", message: "This is demo message.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Application Name", attributes: [
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13),
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.greenColor()
            ])
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        confirmAlert.addAction(defaultAction)

        confirmAlert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(confirmAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```