# UIAlertController customization

Tags: ios, customization, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to customize my UIAlertController with a dark theme.
I'm aiming for something like this [image]

I'm trying different things, including the suggestion I found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29122883/1817873, but for some reason only the first button gets colored while the cancel button keeps staying white.

Here is my code:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *deleteAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Confirm" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
[alert addAction:deleteAction];
[alert addAction:cancelAction];

UIView *firstView = alert.view.subviews.firstObject;
UIView *nextView = firstView.subviews.firstObject;
nextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try UIAlertActionStyleDefault to the style of the cancel action

Comment: Be careful - customizing the UIAlertController like this might get you rejected from the App Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas?

Yes. Give up. An alert controller is very limited, and you should stick to what it does. But it is just a presented view controller, and nothing stops you from making your own presented view controller that looks and acts just like an alert, and since it is your view controller, it's your view and you can do whatever you like.

Comment: You are right. 
I ended up doing my custom UIView and simulate the same behaviour.
Thank you

Comment: Excellent! You might want to post your custom action sheet code on github; it might be useful to others. I have custom alert code: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 But my code is for an alert, not an action sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still struggling with this, I have [a library](https://github.com/danielsaidi/Sheeeeeeeeet) that may be of help. It lets you create custom action sheets. It has a bunch of built-in types and can be extended and restyled as well.

Comment: Please remember to disclose your affinity with a project when you link to it.