# Change Background Color of the UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, uialertcontroller

my code is

```
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"Touch ID for Eceipt" message:@"Touch ID or Enter Password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *cancelButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                    //Handle your yes please button action here
                                }];
    alert.view.tintColor=[UIColor blueColor];          
    alert.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];   //this code changes the alert view color
    alert.view.layer.cornerRadius=10;
    [alert addAction:cancelButton];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

by this code, I can achieve a "blue coloured Cancel Button" and a white coloured alert view and a gray coloured background..

What i need is more dark Colour BG.
here is my output screenshot [above_code_output_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2lB5.png)
i Need the BG like this screenshot [actually_what_i_need_is_this_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moQko.png)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Narendra Pandey-> tried that but the result came was, its change the ALTER CONTENTVIEW COLOUR.it doesn't change the BG of the Alertcontentview.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293656/change-uialertcontroller-background-color