# How to decrease the Font size of a button in UIAlertView,is there any way to do so?

Tags: ios, uialertview

i am using UIalertView,

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:appname
                                                message:@"some blah blah!"
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Free content", nil];
[alert show];
```

here i want to reduce the font size of "Free content" when alert view pops up(something like arial-9)font,is there any way to reduce the font or design it in a custom way?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You cannot customize the appearance of UIAlertView,

because the view hierarchy for this class is **private** and must **not be modified**.

for more see UIAlertView Class Reference:[UIAlertView Class Reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html)

why not?

> you can use Custom AlertView with desire apperance

see the below link how to create custom alertviews with your desired apperance [CustomAlertView Sample](http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.in/2013/04/creating-custom-alert-view-for-iphone.html)

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView is deprecated as of iOS 8. You need to use UIAlertController from iOS8 onwards. You can use Key-Value coding to set UIAlertController's button font using attributedTitle key.

More on the answer provided here.

[UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

Comment: After exploring the linked answer you provided, I found that you can change the color of a UIAlertController's button, but not the font.