# UIAlertAction list of values

Tags: ios, swift, uialertaction

I'm trying to figure out how to change font type for UIAlertAction title.
I'm assuming, it can be done by setting a value for particular key.
For instance, to set an image you would do this:

```
action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
```

Is there a list of all keys that are available? I can't figure out which key to use for changing font, aligning the title left/right, etc...

Comment: is there a way to use attributed string for UIAlertAction title?

Answer (score 24):

`class_copyIvarList` may be what you need.

### Swift

```
extension UIAlertAction {
    static var propertyNames: [String] {
        var outCount: UInt32 = 0
        guard let ivars = class_copyIvarList(self, &outCount) else {
            return []
        }
        var result = [String]()
        let count = Int(outCount)
        for i in 0..<count {
            let pro: Ivar = ivars[i]
            guard let ivarName = ivar_getName(pro) else {
                continue
            }
            guard let name = String(utf8String: ivarName) else {
                continue
            }
            result.append(name)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

then

```
print(UIAlertAction.propertyNames)
```

and the output is

```
["_title", "_titleTextAlignment", "_enabled", "_checked", "_isPreferred", "_imageTintColor", "_titleTextColor", "_style", "_handler", "_simpleHandler", "_image", "_shouldDismissHandler", "__descriptiveText", "_contentViewController", "_keyCommandInput", "_keyCommandModifierFlags", "__representer", "__interfaceActionRepresentation", "__alertController"]
```

Comment: Has anyone experimented with each key?

Comment: Could you give an example for each key? it's helpful

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to change the colour of the UIAlertAction title.

```
 UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"alert view"
                                          message:@"hello alert controller"
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {

                                   }];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController: alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

OR

Check this link-[UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

Comment: There are several things wrong with this approach now: (Xcode 8.2.1)

It only affects the default and cancel buttons, not the title (or message), and 
in some versions of iOS the .tintColor should be changed after presentViewController is called. 

A better approach to set the button color is to place 
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:appBarColor]; in your app delegate.