# UIAlertAction Button Text Alignment Left

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I want to align `UIAlertAction` text alignment to Left and add the icon as in image shown. I spent lot of time on google to get the solution but not found the right answer. Every body post for the alert title not for the alert action title.
[image]

Please suggest me the right way for **swift**.

Thanks!!

Comment: There's no public API to do this with UIAlertController.

Answer (score 24):

You can do that with bellow example code. Easy and Simple.

**Swift 5**

```
let actionSheetAlertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
let cancelActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cancelActionButton)
    
    
let documentsActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Documents", style: .default, handler: nil)
actionSheetAlertController.addAction(documentsActionButton)
documentsActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "doccument"), forKey: "image")
documentsActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
    
let cameraActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: nil)
actionSheetAlertController.addAction(cameraActionButton)
cameraActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "camera"), forKey: "image")
cameraActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
    
let galleryActionButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: nil)
actionSheetAlertController.addAction(galleryActionButton)
galleryActionButton.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "gallery"), forKey: "image")
galleryActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
    
actionSheetAlertController.view.tintColor = kTHEME_COLOR
self.present(actionSheetAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Just Single line Code
actionButton.setValue(kCAAlignmentLeft, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")

Comment: 'kCAAlignmentLeft' has been renamed to 'CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left' from swift 5

Answer (score 11):

An updated version to swift 5.0 of `kCAAlignmentLeft` (as answered by @Niraj Solanki [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51658738/9240515)) is `CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left`
So the code should be as below:

**Swift 5.0**

```
documentsActionButton.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
```

Comment: It works for left, but doesn't work for right alignment!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54284170/826946 for more customization options

Answer (score 7):

You can do that with bellow example code. 
Replace image name with your image

**Swift 3**

```
 let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
 let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
  // Do something
 }
 let cameraImage = UIImage(named: "icon_camera")
 camera.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: "image")
 camera.setValue(0, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
 actionSheet.addAction(camera)
```

Answer (score 1):

fastest and simplest implementation for this case:

```
extension UIAlertAction {
    func addImage(_ image: UIImage){
        setValue(image, forKey: "image")
        setValue(0, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
    }
}
```

using:

```
let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default, handler: nil)
editAction.addImage(UIImage(systemName: "square.and.pencil")!)
alertSheet.addAction(editAction)
```

NOTE:
CATextLayerAlignmentMode — is not what you need. Because right alignment doesn't work with it! Better use numeric literals:

- 0 - left
- 1 - center
- 2 - right

for universal use i would create this enum:

```
enum AlertActionAlignment:Int {
    case left, center, right
}

...
setValue(align.rawValue, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said in comments, UIAlertController do not provide customization of its view. However, you can build your own action sheet view or use some third parties, like https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLActionController.

Answer (score 0):

For alert action, you can use this code,

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "",  preferredStyle: .actionSheet)    

let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { action in
            //add alert action
        }

camera.setValue(CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left, forKey: "titleTextAlignment")
let icon = UIImage.(named: "your image file name")

camera.setValue(icon, forKey: "image")

actionSheet.addAction(camera)

present(actionSheet, animated: true)
```

Using this code, you can achieve an alert action sheet with image and left aligned alert action text.