# how to color specific words in a uialertview or UIAlertController ? (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, colors, uialertview

is there a way to color some specific words in uialertview ?
I mean, can I color the word RED as red and at the same time GREEN as green  ?

[image]

Can someone bring me on the right way?

Comment: In general you would use NSAttributedString for that, but I do not think that is available for UIAlertViews, for UIAlertController however you might be able to get somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color

Comment: @luk2302 lol, wut? You made this comment before telling skyddict that he's not asking about controllers?

Comment: @Fogmeister yup! because at that time it was only about uialertviews - i was not sure he actually knew about uialertcontrollers and what os he was targeting

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could make use of `NSAttributedString` and `UIAlertController`:

```
    let strings = [["text" : "My String red\n", "color" : UIColor.redColor()], ["text" : "My string green", "color" : UIColor.greenColor()]];

    var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    for configDict in strings {
        if let color = configDict["color"] as? UIColor, text = configDict["text"] as? String {
            attributedString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color]))
        }
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage")

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
        style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    }

    presentViewController(alert,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
```

You use the key `attributedMessage` to assign an attributed string for the message and the key `attributedTitle` for the title.

I couldn't find a solution for `UIAlertView` that works but all of them use private variables which is not good practice. You should know that `UIAlertView` is deprecate from iOS 8 on, so if you are not targeting lower, you should not use it, instead use `UIAlertController`

Comment: He is however asking about UIAlertViews, not controllers.

Comment: UIAlertController is also ok for me. But above example shows me only the Red text "Red". This works fine, but how to color only specific words. In my sample I should have the word GREEN -> green and at the same time RED -> red. Is this possible with mentoined solution.

Comment: @luk2302 for iOS8 UIAlertView is deprecated. If you're targeting iOS8 then you shouldn't be using UIAlertView anyway.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much for your effort. Thats great. I can use the UIAlertController with my IOS8 environment. My Title was probably missleading with UIAlertView. I am still new to OIS and version. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I already answered there https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047809/6726766 - as an alternative to private API you could use https://github.com/AntonPoltoratskyi/NativeUI

`pod 'NativeUI/Alert', '~> 1.0'`

It looks exactly like native alert, but configurable enough.