# UIAlertViewController: Separate tint colors for cancel and other action buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

Is it possible to give separate tint colors for cancel and other action buttons?. Currently I am changing the tint color as `controller.view.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

but it changes the tint color for cancel button too. I need to set different tint color say red to the cancel button. Please help me guys.

Comment: use destructive style for cancel button to get red color text!

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri, Sorry didn't get you. Could you please explain?

Comment: I meant to say that use the UIAlertAction style as UIAlertActionStyleDestructive for the cancel button.

Comment: this also could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri, thanks for the help, the color of UIAlertActionStyleDestructive is default red that is fine. But is there any way to position that button? I want the cancel button at the bottom. Cancel button above all buttons looks weird.

Comment: it's the way you add action to your alert controller. If you want cancel button to be at top, add it first! If you want it last, add it last!

Comment: Ohh!, how dumb I am, adding cancel button first and expecting it to be last :P. Thanks a lot Taja bhai. Everything is working as expected :)

Answer (score 9):

set the colour on the alert action as follows:

```
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"....

[cancel setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"titleTextColor"];
```

swift:

```
let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) 
cancelAction.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
```

Comment: How can I use custom font in cancel button?

Comment: how can I change custom background-colour for the cancel button