# UIAlertController custom font doesn't work at iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uialertcontroller

UIAlertController custom font doesn't work.

The following code is a function `ShowActionSheetAsync`, show `ActionSheet`.
At this point, I want to change the font of `ActionSheet`. I have tried several ways, but it didn't work well. Is there good solution?

```
public Task<bool> ShowActionSheetAsync()
{
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var alert = new UIAlertController
    {
        Title = "title"
    };
    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(
            "button1",
            UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
            _ => source.SetResult(true)));
    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(
        "cancel",
        UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,
        _ => source.SetResult(false)));

    // [Block 1]
    var viewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
    ViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, delegate
    {
        // [Block 2]
    });

    // [Block 3]
    return source.Task;
}
```

**First attempt**
The following code does not work properly.

- When I put the code on `[Block 1]` or `[Block 2]`

  - It does not work at all
- When I put the code on `[Block 3]`

  - Applies only when the first show `ActionSheet`. From the second times, it does not work

`UILabel.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(UIActionSheet)).Font 
    = UIFont.FromName(StyleResources.MediumFontName, 20);`

**The second attempt**
The following code also does not work properly.

- When I put the code on `[Block 2]`

  - After showing the default font for a short time, showing the custom font
- When I put the code on `[Block 3]`

  - it work on only `cancel` button

`FindDescendantViews<UILabel>()` is a extension method for `UIView` and returns all child view of appropriate type.

```
var labels = alert.View.FindDescendantViews<UILabel>();
foreach (var label in labels)
{
    label.Font = UIFont.FromName(StyleResources.MediumFontName, 20);
}
```

Comment: Have you tired with `label.Font = UIFont(name: StyleResources.MediumFontName, size: 20)` ?

Comment: What is difference with my second attempt and your code? @JigarTarsariya

Comment: Have you looked into the [UIAppearance protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30463812/2518285)?

Comment: you means my first attempt? (UILabel.AppearanceWhenContainedIn) @Brett Donald

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertController` `UILabels` font and color can be set via KVC using the `attributedTitle` key. Use this in `[Block 3]`

```
func changeAlert(alert: UIAlertController, backgroundColor: UIColor, textColor: UIColor, buttonColor: UIColor?) {
    let view = alert.view.firstSubview().firstSubview()
    view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0

    // set color to UILabel font
    setSubviewLabelsToTextColor(textColor, view: view)

    // set font to alert via KVC, otherwise it'll get overwritten
    let titleAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: alert.title!,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)])
    alert.setValue(titleAttributed, forKey: "attributedTitle")


    let messageAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: alert.message!,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)])
    alert.setValue(messageAttributed, forKey: "attributedMessage")


    // set the buttons to non-blue, if we have buttons
    if let buttonColor = buttonColor {
        alert.view.tintColor = buttonColor
    }
}

func setSubviewLabelsToTextColor(textColor: UIColor, view:UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
            label.textColor = textColor
        } else {
            setSubviewLabelsToTextColor(textColor, view: subview)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a solution about my question.
i want to change Button style(font) not a title & message styles

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color btw KVC is Key-Value Coding https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001838-SW1

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution here. I created a custom AlertThemeConfigurator that recursively runs through all the subviews looking for UILabels, then sets the themed attributedText on them for the title, message, and different types of actions. Feel free to style the attributed strings appropriately.

```
class AlertThemeConfigurator {

   class func configureAlertViewController(alertController : UIAlertController) {
        AlertLabelConfigurator.adjustLabels(inView: alertController.view, alertController: alertController)
   }

   class AlertLabelConfigurator {

       class func adjustLabels(inView view : UIView, alertController : UIAlertController) {
            for subview in view.subviews {

                if subview is UILabel {
                    adjustLabel((subview as! UILabel), inAlertViewController : alertController)
                }

                adjustLabels(inView :subview,  alertController : alertController)
            }
       }

       class func adjustLabel(label : UILabel, inAlertViewController alertController : UIAlertController) {
            if label.text == alertController.title {
                label.attributedText = attributedTitle(label.text!)
            } else if label.text == alertController.message {
                label.attributedText = attributedBody(label.text!)
            }

            for action in alertController.actions {
                if label.text == action.title {
                    switch action.style {
                    case .Default:
                        label.attributedText = attributedDefaultAction(action.title!)
                    case .Cancel:
                        label.attributedText = attributedCancelAction(action.title!)
                    case .Destructive:
                        label.attributedText = attributedDestructiveAction(action.title!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        class func attributedTitle(title : String) -> NSAttributedString {
             let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 20)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName :  UIColor.greenColor()]
             return NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
        }

        class func attributedBody(title : String) -> NSAttributedString {
             let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 12)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName :  UIColor.orangeColor()]
             return NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
        }

        class func attributedDefaultAction(title : String) -> NSAttributedString {
             let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName :  UIColor.yellowColor()]
             return NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
        }

        class func attributedCancelAction(title : String) -> NSAttributedString {
             let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName :  UIColor.purpleColor()]
             return NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
        }

        class func attributedDestructiveAction(title : String) -> NSAttributedString {
             let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName :  UIColor.redColor()]
             return NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
        }
    }
}
```

To present it call

```
 let alert = CustomAlertController(title: "Title", message:"Message" , preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
 presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 AlertThemeConfigurator.configureAlertViewController(alert)
```

Comment: I think it's not allowed to subclass an UIAlertController according to Apple's guidelines.

Comment: I just updated the solution not to inherit from the UIAlertViewController :) Hope this helps

Comment: @BhavukJain I just updated one more time, and created a private class to perform the label theming, so that the methods are not exposed

Comment: @BhavukJain just realized I had a type in there, wasn't calling adjustLabels on AlertLabelConfigurator. Fixed it up

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed to either subclass or change default things of an UIAlertController. You need to make a custom view for it.