# How to change font size in iOS Alert Message Box Title and Message with Swift

Tags: swift, uialertview, font-size, uialertcontroller

I would like to change the **font size** of Message box *title* and *message* with Swift. 
I don't want font color or font family. I just only want to change the font size and line height.

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Title", attributes: [
NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15) //your font here,
NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()])
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "",  preferredStyle: .Alert)

alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
}

presentViewController(alert,
animated: true,
completion: nil)
```

Comment: which version of iOS you are using

Comment: You may refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color

Comment: My development Target is 9.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change key for it

Please check below code:

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test Title", message: "Custom Fonts in Alert Controller", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let strAction = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Presenting the great...")
    strAction.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30), range: NSMakeRange(24, 11))
    alert.setValue(action, forKey: "attributedMessage")// change key name if you want to change title font with attributedTitle

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Some title", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```