# How can I set accessibilityIdentifier to UIAlertActions?

Tags: swift, accessibility, uitest

First of all yes I have seen this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117410/how-can-i-set-accessibilityidentifier-to-uialertcontroller) but there is currently no answer.

The root problem is that I am currently `XCUITesting` my app which is localized so the `UIAlertAction`s are localized so I can't find the button.

I could do a hack wherein I'll include all the `Localizable.strings` on my UITesting bundle then get the localized version when trying to fetch the button like this.

```
let localizedAlertTitle = ...(some function to fetch localized name)
let localizedButtonName = ...(some function to fetch localized name)
self.app
    .alerts[localizedAlertTitle]
    .buttons[localizedButtonName]
    .tap()
```

Another way is to probably do the hack said by this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40688141/5928180) but it's too hacky and has boilerplate.

Is there a way to set the `accessibilityIdentifier` on a UIAlertAction?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. Any good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what situation was with this in 2018, but nowadays accessibility identifier can be assigned to `UIAlertAction`s (since it conforms to `UIAccessibilityIdentification`):

```swift
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Title", style: .destructive) { _ in
  // Handle action here.
}
action.accessibilityIdentifier = "ActionIdentifier"
```

And I have no problems to use in in my UI tests:

```swift
app.buttons["ActionIdentifier"]
```