# Is any other possible to edit UIAlertAction title font size and style?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, guard, uialertaction

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Some title", style: .Default, handler: nil)let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some title")

let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 1.5, range: range)
attributedText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Semibold", size: 20.0)!, range: range)

alert.addAction(action)

presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

// this has to be set after presenting the alert, otherwise the internal property __representer is nil
**guard let label = action.valueForKey("__representer")?.valueForKey("label") as? UILabel else { return }
label.attributedText = attributedText**
```

This guard label is not working properly. Can any one say is any another method is there for to set the custom font for uialertaction in swift

Comment: For swift updated code method any one can give answer

Comment: Have u checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41299305/5362916

Comment: @UmaMadhavi.. Yes i checked this method.. In that i cant to set the alertaction custom font

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36136625/5362916 this one

Comment: its not wokring for alertaction.. I already tried that method

Comment: Prefer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530577/4803556

Comment: I prefered this method.. In that these lines are not working guard let label = action.valueForKey("__representer")?.valueForKey("label") as? UILabel else { return }
label.attributedText = attributedText