# NSMutableAttributedString as UIAlertAction's title - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsmutableattributedstring, uialertaction

Is it possible to set a NSMutableAttributedString as AlertAction's title?
My aim is to visualize a math expression with a good design in my UIAlertAction's title.

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: myNSMutableAttributedString, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {(result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Sooo how about you try?

Comment: I put in title: String(describing: myNSMutableAttributedString) but obviously is not the good way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **not possible** to use an `NSAttributedString` for a `UIAlertAction`'s title without accessing private APIs, as the method for setting the `attributedTitle` to an attributed string does not work here ([see this question for details on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)).

I would create a custom class or use an alert library for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Some ideas for well alert library?