# UIAlertController message with multiple colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I would like to change the second sentence to a different color.

```
UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController
    alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning!!!" message:@"This is the first sentence.\r\n\n
This is the second sentence I want a different color.\r\n\n
This is the third sentence.)"
preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

Comment: `UIAlertController` does not support attributed text. Write or find a custom alert class that does.

Comment: I would also ask the question, what value does the color add to the second sentence?  Granted, I'm not answering the direct question, but consider the possibility that the fact `UIAlertController` doesn't support attributed text is a clue that alerts aren't intended to be highly customized for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)