# Can we change AlertController button fonts?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring, uialertcontroller

I have gone through different solutions on stackoverflow and other websites. But I just know about change about title and message fonts and colors. But Can we change button font's too?

I know we can change button textcolor but I want to change font's too. Means I want to customise whole alertcontroller including buttons too.

Comment: You can create your own AlertController. Create a new ViewController in Storyboard or via code then present it modally

Comment: That's why I specify default Alertcontroller, I don't want to create ViewController. @SahilManchanda

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

Comment: @Scriptable I specify my question that I want to change Default button's font style. I know we can change title and message font style and color. Just read my question carefully and then comment.

Comment: the comment says 'possible', not that it definitely was.

Comment: @Scriptable I am looking for an answer, just possible is not my answer. from that duplicate question I am not getting my answer. Just look at that duplicate question it's all answer's are define customize alwertcontroller but excluding button font style.

Comment: I think the answer is that you need to create a custom alert controller. I dont think you can do it any other way unless you use a library to create custom one for you

Comment: So that's impossible in your way to do it in default alertcontroller. I know i have to create custom alertcontroller but if it is possible then it saves lot of time of mine @Scriptable

Comment: Did you tried with attributedText?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller):

> The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not
> support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
> must not be modified.

Modification is only possible with the help of Private API. which is not a good practice and App may get rejected for using Private API.