# Change Font for all UIAlertController in the app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios10, uialertcontroller

How to change the font for all the `UIAlertController`s in the app?

Is there any way like how we do it for other UIElements

Ex:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Also changing UIAlertViewController fonts, colors etc is private API. So no release at the AppStore

[UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)