# How to add a detail label to UIAlertAction?

Tags: ios

I'm studing iOS, and I got a question. 
How should I do to add a detail label to UIAlertAction? Like UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

Thanks.

Comment: you should keep in mind what is said in the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller#1968629

Comment: Hey & welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is too broad and doesn't make clear what exactly you're asking about and where you're stuck. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Sorry, I will read it later.

Answer (score 0):

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "My Message",
     attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 20)!])

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.setValue(attributedString, forKey: "attributedMessage")

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

alert.addAction(cancelAction)

present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

try this one..

Comment: Sorrr, what I need is UIAlertAction, not UIAlertController.

Comment: just change below line

with 
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

Answer (score 0):

You can not add detailedText(two labels) in `UIAlertAction`. But Instead of that you can make your own customized alert view and action buttons. If you don't have time, you can search for third party libraries.

Also if `UIAlertAction` has ability to set attributed text, you could append two lines(by adding "\n" in `NSAttributedString` with small font to display like detailLabel) of text as `UIAlertAction` title. But unfortunately there is no public API to set attributed String as UIAlertAction title. But there is a private API as mentioned in this answer [UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)