# UIWebView and URLRequest Interception

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, wkwebview

I am trying to understand the request interception problem in UIWebView so I can start looking into WKWebView.

What I don't understand is, UIWebView has its own method for interception which is shouldStartLoadWithRequest, but it seems like most of people are still implementing a custom NSURLProtocol to do interception. I am curious why most people choose not to use UIWebView's method? What are the differences here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIAlertController custom font, size, color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460706/uialertcontroller-custom-font-size-color)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is simply load or reject the request, you can do this in `WKWebView` by becoming its `WKWebViewNavigationDelegate` and implementing `webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)`

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    let request = navigationAction.request

    let policy: WKNavigationActionPolicy
    if request.path.contains("something_bad") {
        policy = .cancel
    } else {
        policy = .allow
    }
    decisionHandler(policy)
}
```

Comment: I understand, but for my understanding this class only intercepts the url, doesn't intercept any resources and Ajax requests. I am wondering if UIWebViews shouldStartLoad is the same

Comment: The method on question only captures page loads, not other resource loads.  Chances are those folks want to intercept image loads, script loads, etc.